# Mysterious "settings" menu in phonegap app?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

a user just sent me this screenshot: [image: User View]
You can see a "settings" menu on the bottom and as the font indicates, my (phonegap) app has nothing to do with that whatsoever. He is running Android Jelly Bean. Does anyone know where this menu is coming from and more importantly, how to get rid of it? Clickin on it doesn't do anything, by the way.

Comment: He also just informed me that it eventually goes away again. Still, I'd prefer if it didn't come up in the first place, but I can't find anything about this phenomenon on the internet. What is this?

Comment: Looks like he is using a custom ROM as the font in the 'Settings' matches the status bar. He might want to ask the ROM builder if there is some special gesture/key press to get to the settings menu.

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually didn't even think of custom ROMs. I will ask him and if he confirms, I'll let it go as it's a) not my fault and b) it goes away after a few seconds. I was already wondering why no other JB user reported this. I'll let you know what he says.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the explanation. If you want to post this in the form of an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It was simply an automatically generated settings menu (in Java) that, per default, only contains the string "Settings".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he is using a custom ROM as the font in the 'Settings' matches the status bar and it doesn't look like a standard Android system font. He might want to ask the ROM builder if there is some special gesture/key press to get to the settings menu.

Comment: I just noticed that I actually get the same menu (in normal font) and I certainly don't have a custom ROM. I'm pretty sure it's just the standard settings menu, just that I don't fill it with anything, so it just displays "Settings".

Comment: I just solved it. There was simply an automatically generated menu for the main activity that displays the title "Settings".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but what you need to do is remove the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` from your main *activity class* (The same *class* in which you load the url)